# Next.js 13 - How to get params from url using userParams and statically pre render components at built time at same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am learning latest nextjs 13.4 and I have created a page on route `/notes/[note]`. Now I want to get the note param from url which I am doing using `import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'`.

Along with this, I want to statically Pre Render data for this route, so when I build the project, this component get its html file generated in `.next` folder. For this, I am setting up pre-defined note ids using [generateStaticParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params) (it works like getStaticPaths in previous next.js versions).

Now the problem is that, when I leave it as server component, `useParams` doesn't work and throws an error and when I set it a client component using 'user client' at top, it gets compiled but Static Pre-rendering for given 4 note ids doesn't work.

**How to make both the things work for this component?**

```
'use client'
import styles from '../../page.module.css'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'

async function getNoteData(id : string) {
  const note = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`);
  if(!note) {
    throw new Error("No data found.");
  }
  return note.json();
}

interface Note {
  userId: string;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: string;
}

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{note: '1'}, {note: '2'}, {note: '3'}, {note: '4'}]
}

export default async function Note({params}: {params: {note: string}}) {
  const param = useParams();
  const todo : Note = await getNoteData(param.note);
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>Note Page</h1>
      <div className={styles.description}>
          <p>{todo?.title}</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

When I remove 'use client' from top and remove userParams from file. When I build project, 4 html files successfully gets generated as shown in image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the code below.

**Note:**
I did not use Typescript, as I was already on a JS environment. So please infer types where it complains. And I also opted for Es6.

```
'use client'
import styles from '../../page.module.css'

// interface Note {
//   userId: string;
//   id: number;
//   title: string;
//   completed: string;
// }

export const generateStaticParams = () => {
    return [{ note: '1' }, { note: '2' }, { note: '3' }, { note: '4' }];
}

export const getNoteData = async (id) => {
    const note = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`); // it returns a promise;
    const noteData = await note.json();

    if (!noteData) {
        throw new Error("No data found.");
    }
    console.log(noteData) // log it to see what you get

    return noteData;
}

export const Note = async ({ params }) => {
    console.log(params); // log it to see what you get

    const { slug } = params;
    const todo = await getNoteData(slug);

    console.log(todo);  // log it to see if it got here

    // display loader until result comes
    if (!todo) {
        return <p>Loading</p>
    }

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <h1>Note Page</h1>
            <div className={styles.description}>
                <p>{todo?.title}</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Note;
```

More info here:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params and

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#generating-static-params

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when we are using 'use client' at top, how it will be pre-rendered? Can where are you getting [note] value from url?

Comment: Next.js does the pre-rendering for you. generateStaticParams, ensures it's not done on every request. This runs before the corresponding Layouts or Pages are generated, then Next.js automatically deduplicates the fetch requests for the same data... This should work for you, since you are statically Pre Rendering data at build time.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting notes from the route /notes/[note].

Since you are statically generating routes at build time. As seen it the code above... 
It can be accessed using useParams.

You can check on Static and Dynamic Data Fetching for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping and https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering